# Find usage of ServceAccount in Kubernates cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a **Kubernates Cluster** in bare metal of three nodes.
I have applied a couple of **yaml** files of different services.
Now I would like to make order in the cluster and **clean** some orphaned kube objects.
To do that I need to understand the set of pods or other entities which use or refer a certain **ServiceAccount**.

For example, I can dig ClusterRoleBinding of the, say, admin-user and investigate it:

```
kubectl get сlusterrolebinding admin-user
```

But is there a good `kubectl` options combination to find **all the usages/references** of some **ServiceAccount**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all resources using a service account with the following command:

```
kubectl get rolebinding,clusterrolebinding --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.subjects[0].name=="YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME")]}[{.roleRef.kind},{.roleRef.name}];{end}' | tr ";" "\n"
```

You just need to replace `YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME` to the one you are investigating.

I tested this command on my cluster and it works.

Let me know if this solution helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much, mWatney! This worked for me. At least I got objects which I have to investigate furthermore.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/FairwindsOps/rbac-lookup). After installing via homebrew or krew you can use it find a service account and look at its role, scope, source. It does not tell which pods are referring to it but still a useful tool.

```
rbac-lookup serviceaccountname --output wide --kind serviceaccount
```